# How to do browser zoom in effect on click

Tags: jquery, html, browser, zooming

I want to add a browser zoom effect when a user clicks on a button.
This is for elderly people so they can zoom in on the text to make it easier to read.
I dont want to make the actual text bigger as it will mess up the layout of the webpage.
How can i do this?

I have seen the A A A buttons on several sites which achieve similar.

Comment: The A A A that you see on many sites does exactly what you don't want to do: Enlarge the text.

Comment: Post your code please.. What have you tried?

Comment: have not tried anything yet, looked at several text enlarge plugins but i would prefer a browser zoom plugin.  think have seen this on a uk government site, but cant find it again now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that if you need that you could create 3 different buttons that would toggle active class on  tag and each class should have some font-size definition.

```
<a data-size="small">small</a>
<a data-size="normal">normal</a>
<a data-size="large">large</a>

$("a").on("click", function(){
    $("html").removeClass().addClass($(this).data("size"));
});

html.small{font-size:12px;}
html.normal{font-size:20px;}
html.large{font-size:36px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct browser control itself should not be driven by a script, it would be dangerous in some cases. Browsers implement zoom in different ways and there is no "native API" to do this as far as I know.

The closest you have is altering image and font sizes. Not the answer you were hoping for, I know.